# What are the ways in which XSS can be done in innerHTML

Tags: xss

Server has blacklisted `<img>` and `<a>` tags in input.
Server does:

```
var myvar = url.searchParams.get('query'))
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = myvar
```

`<img>` and `<a>` tags are not working. What are other tags/ ways on which I can do XSS on innerHTML?

Comment: Please provide additional information, such as more of your code, headers etc

Comment: The context of interpretation is important. how does this translate into your DOM?  (and you still can use hundreds of other tags if only a and img are not allowed!)

Comment: You can use an <input> tag with events like onfocus. Unfortunately, autofocus doesn't work in innerHTML so user interaction is required. You may have some luck with a <video> tag